# Remove matched portion of a string if it matches a pattern

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have a field "model" in my table Vehicles (which has just under 59,000 entries) which may have a value of something like:

```
Roadline (09-14)
```

I want to remove the (XX-XX) if it exists and fill in the "treated" value to a field modelname.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple solution is to use [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to isolate the portion before `(`. You can use [`REGEXP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) to make sure the pattern matches but, unfortunately, you cannot use it to capture matches.

```
SELECT
  model,
  CASE
    WHEN model REGEXP '\\([0-9]+-[0-9]+\\)$' THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(model, '(', 1)
    ELSE model
  END AS modelname
FROM vehicles
```

Once you have made sure the data looks OK, you can update the other column like this:

```
UPDATE vehicles
SET modelname = CASE
  WHEN model REGEXP '\\([0-9]+-[0-9]+\\)$' THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(model, '(', 1)
  ELSE model
END
```

Comment: Perhaps you can suggest how I can trap the data without the (XX-XX) and update it into a field modelname. Thanks!

Comment: @Jim see revised answer. Note that it will not work if the model contains more than one `(`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it out and report back.